# Allow values in edittext(Android)

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my Android project I want to put certain condition on edittext that it can accepts only following list of values  :-

```
!#$%&'()*+,-./:;<>=?@[]\_`{}|~^"*abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789
```

and not the the values like shown in keyboard such as ©,® :- [image]

Kindly provide me solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this in the XML file.

```
<EditText 
  android:inputType="text" 
  android:digits="!#$%&'()*+,-./:;<>=?@[]\_`{}|~^"*abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789" 
  android:hint="Only letters, digits, _ and - allowed"
/>
```